# Postgresql-Nodejs connection error (ECONNREFUSED) Windows 10

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, wsl-2, econnrefused

A couple of weeks ago I started a blog app. For this I used postgresql as database on the backend. Back then, the application worked fine I was able to fetch data from the frontend to the backend server running express. Today I decided to visit the project again but ran into an error. After some error handling and a bunch of searching around on StackOverflow I was able to get this message:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1141:16) {
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 5432
}
```

The postgres server is running on port 5432 and NOT in docker (This is where I find the issue happend most of the time with other people).

Below I will post the full code but the issue happens here:

```
const { Client } = require('pg');

const client = new Client({
    user: 'jonas',
    host: 'localhost',
    database: 'Blog_db',
    password: '1518',
    port: '5432',
});

client.connect().catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
});
```

(Btw this is the right password and username because I am able to access already existing data via pgAdmin).

I don't understand why it isn't connecting.

I have tried:

1. Restarting my pc
2. Restarting the service in services (This is a windows machine)
3. Reinstalling postgresql (fully)

Now that I am writing this post, I just realized I updated my windows to version 2004 and wsl2. Previously this was wsl1. Can this have anything to do with it? I just wanted to start a new project, again with Postgres. I think I will temporarily use mongodb and monk or mongoose until the issue is fixed.

Added 3th August: After some more reading on stackoverflowI found out that this could have to do with the amount of instances of postgresql server running. This is what I got from taskmanager:[Image of taskmanager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vi442.png)
Is it normal that there 3 instances running? If not how do I fix this?

My full code if you are interested (not necessary I think) :

```
//Express imports
const express = require('express'); //Main express lib
const morgan = require('morgan'); //Lib for loging get and post requests
const cors = require('cors'); //Only allowing the backend to talk to the frontend
const helmet = require('helmet'); //Deleting and adding html-headers to mask express

//Express app setup
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(helmet());
app.use(
    cors({
        origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
    })
);

//Postgresql import
const { Client } = require('pg'); //Main postgres nodejs lib

//Other
require('dotenv').config(); //Use environement variables definded in .env file

console.log(JSON.parse(process.env.PG_CLIENT_CONNECT_INFO));
//Create a connection client to database
const client = new Client({
    user: 'jonas',
    host: 'localhost',
    database: 'Blog_db',
    password: '1518',
    port: '5432',
});

client.connect().catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
});

//Get the blogs from the database in JSON format
app.get('/API/getBlogs', (req, res) => {
    const query = `
    SELECT * FROM blogs
    ORDER BY id ASC
    `;

    client
        .query(query)
        .then(response => {
            res.json(response.rows);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
            res.send(err);
        });
});

//Add blogs to database as JSON object converted to SQL query
app.post('/API/addBlogs', (req, res) => {
    const query = `
        INSERT INTO blogs (author, title, content)
        VALUES ('${req.body.author}', '${req.body.title}', '${req.body.content}')
    `;

    client
        .query(query)
        .then(response => {
            console.log(`${response.rows} \n Successfully added requested data.`);
            res.sendStatus(200);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
            res.send(err);
        });
});

const port = process.env.EXPRESS_PORT || 1337;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`The app is now listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

Comment: Is your express server running inside docker?

Comment: No it is running from the wsl2 ubuntu system and postrgesql is installed in windows 10 not wsl2 ubuntu.

Comment: "*Btw this is the right password and username*" - you might not want to post your credentials online though :-) Please make sure to change them!

Comment: I yet again started troubleshooting and found out that my suspicion was right. wsl2 broke the application. If I copy all the files except node_modules, then do a npm install and run the backend from outside wsl it works. Anyone knows how to fix this? For now I am going to switch back to wsl1, because this works fine.

Comment: Did you install Postgres on WSL? I bet you have to. Try it with `sudo apt install postgresql postgresql-contrib`